# Как получить последнее значение в БД от авторизованного юзера в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

**Вот мой код:**

```
$game_of_user = \DB::table('games')->where('user_id',  Auth::user()->id)->max('id');
$last_number = $game_of_user->number;
```

Мне нужно получить последнее значение от авторизованного юзера, тобишь как по моему коду, только он почему-то не работает и ошибок не видит.
**Структура БД такая:**
Таблица *games*
столбцы *id, number, user_id*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
\DB::table('games')->where('user_id',  Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

Сортируем по убыванию по полю id, и берем первую запись. Должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо) Ты помог мне) Заработало. А то я не понимал, почему оно не хочет брать.

Comment: Пожалуйста)))))

Answer (score 0):

Или более коротко:

```
\DB::table('games')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->latest()->first();
```

Обратите внимание, что этот метод использует автоматически созданный столбец `created_at` (`$timestamps = true`) в Модели, но может быть отключен по желанию, поэтому у вас будет ошибка, если он не определен.

**UPDATE Laravel 5.7**:

> The Eloquent query builder's **lates**t and **oldest** methods have been
>   updated to respect custom "created at" timestamp columns that may be
>   specified on your Eloquent models. Generally, this should be
>   considered a bug fix; however, it is listed as a breaking change out
>   of caution.

Это значит что эти методы теперь работают не от created_at, а от [getCreatedAtColumn()](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getCreatedAtColumn)